# Spring Integration Migration from 3 to 4

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have multiple services (serviceA, ServiceB ..)using spring integration .  Each service is dependent upon other submodules(which again is using spring integration).

In most of our config xml files we have hard coded the version like below  :
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws-3.0.xsd

I have a task to migrate one service (ServiceA) from spring integration 3 to 4.
I changed the config files to use versionless aliases (e.g. spring-integration.xsd), but as this service is dependent on other services, it looks like I have to change all the dependent services also to spring integration 4.

Is there any other option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't possible if the dependency is on the code level. Spring Integration `3.0` is compatible with Spring Framework `4.x`, but only if you don't use Messaging. In that case an old `org.springframework.integration.Message` isn't compatible with new `org.springframework.messaging.Message`.

See more info about migration in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-3.0-to-4.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: Is there any change in the namespace for spring integration in context files ?

Comment: It isn't related and fully depend on the jar in classpath. Of course you have to use `versionless` schemaLocations